# How to make a script launched by cron to sleep for X seconds?

Tags: php, delay, wait

I 'm improving a cron job which loops a lot of stuff and updates my database. I would like to make ut wait, let's say 30 seconds every 100 requests.

Something like:

```
loop{
     loop{
          query();
     }
     wait(3000); // wait 3 seconds and continue
}
```

Can I do that? If so, is it possible the the cron job times out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set execution time limit to infinity with this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

And then you can use `sleep()` function to pause the execution.

Comment: so i should use that boolean-like?

Comment: @Toni, from the manual (parameter for set_time_limi()): The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

Comment: But i mean, if i set_time_limit(0); then, i can call sleep(3) at anytime all the times i need, right?

Comment: @Toni, yes at any time and for how long you want.

Answer (score 4):

To make a configurable pause, use the [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function.

When launching PHP from the command line (as `cron` does), the [`max_execution_time` is infinite by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), so you won't have to worry about timeouts unless you change it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

See the `sleep()` function. It lets you wait for X seconds.

PS: you may need to also use `set_time_limit()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
// sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php).